# Ubuntu LAMP not responding

Tags: apache, http, ubuntu, timeout

I set up a ubuntu LAMP server, running in a virtualbox ubuntu 16.04.

I have fowarded ports 80, 8080 and 443 in my router, from my external address to the proper webserver machine address (192.168.0.27), as well as allowed them in the ufw. The apache is runnning, I can access it through both 192.168.0.27 and, strange enough, from the same WAN, I can access it though the external IP.

**However, when I try to access it from outside, e.g. a cellphone on 3G, I always get Connection Timed Out. What am I doing wrong?**

Here's my netstat, my apache.conf, ports.conf, UFW and router setup.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And lastly,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you should change the Network adapater to Bridged (It seems you are choosing NAT)

Then you can give an ip to your guest machine other than 10.0.2.15 (or you can leave it if you want)

then open a browser from your host machine and type: ip-address-of-your-guest-machine/...

Comment: Do you mean the adapter in my virtual machine configuration or in my router's? Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is already bridged, enp4s0, but still doesnt work. Do I need to set up a static ip in my network interfaces?